# visual studio 2010 not showing errors anymore

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have not used my Visual Studio 2010 for 2 weeks. Did not even touch my computer and now I am trying to work on a project.
Loaded in the project and none of the errors are shown (not even in the errorlist window). When I click build it says: build succeeded (but a bit too fast for my saying). I have tried to reload the references and even created a new project and copied the code in to it. None of this works. If I then run the project I get current error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
System.MissingMemberException: Der öffentliche Member Domains für den Typ Iref wurde nicht gefunden.
bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)
bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
bei myprogram.myfunction() in projectpath/myprogram.vb:Line 132.
```

Iref is a reference and I am 100 procent sure that the Domains member still exists in this reference.
Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have Option Strict On in your project settings or at the top of your code file?  What happens if you type in an obviously bad line of code and then compile?

Comment: Option Strict is Off. and if I type something like sss = sdfsdf then it gives me the error messages.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the program not checking the references or something because if I write a line of code like: dim str as string = reference.NonexitingFunction then it says nothing...

Comment: Strange.  Does it do the same thing if Option Strict is On?

Comment: Fixed it more or less by putting the strict option on. Not the best solution ever but it will work for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by putting on the Option Strict to ON.
Not really the best solution but will do for the meanwhile

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. I solved this by changing the **Active Solution Platform** to **Mixed Platform**. To do so, go to Configuration Manager and set the Active Solution Platform in the upper right corner.